# Find element by class name

Tags: python, parsing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm trying to find one tag using `we.find_element_by_css_selector('p.p1.transfer strong.ng-binding').text`

The problem is that there is sometimes a 'strong' tag before the tag I'm searching for which is very similar but it's class is: `class="ng-binding ng-hide"` instead of `class="ng-binding"`. But when I try to find it it finds the first tag.

I've tried also `.find_element_by_css_selector('p.p1.transfer').find_element_by_class_name('ng-binding').text` which did not work too, it found the tag which class is named `ng-binding ng-hide`

Have you any advice how to find the tag?

Comment: Have you tried finding by Xpath since you want just one element?

Comment: @lmcphers I know only this way: find_by..... I'm very new in selenium. Could you give me a hint? Thanks

Comment: What Web browser are you using?

Comment: @lmcphers Currenty it is Firefox so I can see what is happening there but It will be PhantomJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let selenium know you don't want the element having `ng-hide` class with the help of [`not` negation pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not):

```
p.p1.transfer strong.ng-binding:not(.ng-hide)
```